# A matrix times its conjugate transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^m$. I'm trying to verify whether $\mathcal{N}(A)=\mathcal{N}(AA^H)$ and $\mathcal{R}(A)=\mathcal{R}(AA^H)$ are true or false, where $\mathcal{N}$ is the null space and $\mathcal{R}$ the range. I'm thinking the inequalities aren't true because you could begin with the range of $A$ being $\mathbb{C}$, but after multiplying $A$ by the conjugate transpose, the range might no longer be $\mathbb{C}$. However, I've been unsuccessful in thinking of counter examples. Am I wrong in my thinking? Any help would be great.

**edit:**
After some further pondering, I'm thinking $\mathcal{N}(A)\neq\mathcal{N}(AA^H)$ but $\mathcal{R}(A)=\mathcal{R}(AA^H)$. My reasoning for this was since $A:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^m$, I can conclude that $AA^H:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n$. Thus, the ranges are equivalent. Additionally, $\mathcal{N}(A)=\mathcal{N}(A^HA)$, but $\mathcal{R}(A)\neq\mathcal{R}(A^HA)$ by the same reasoning above. Is this a correct argument?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A:\mathbb{C}^2\to \mathbb{C}^1$, $A=[1,0]$. Then $AA^H=[1]$, which definitely has a different nullspace than $A$. As for the range, consider $A^T:\mathbb{C^1}\to\mathbb{C^2}$ and arrive at a similar conclusion.